# If a class contains a reference to another class, can I access the initial class from the nested class?

Tags: javascript, class

I'm currently trying to get more experience with Javascript classes, but I can't quite figure out if what I'm trying to achieve is possible.

Here's a simplified version of my code.

```
class A {

  name = "ClassA"

  classB = new B()

}

class B {

  calledFromA() {
    // Is there any way I can print "ClassA" here?
  }

}

const classA = new A();
classA.classB.calledFromA();
```

Class A creates a new class B. Then, from an instance of class A, I would like to call the `calledFromA` method and for it to be able to access everything inside "Class A".

I assume there must be a way of using `this` to do this?

Comment: Your classes are not related to each other, so no, it's not possible.

Comment: "Class A creates a new class B ... and for it to be able to access everything inside "Class A"" maybe take a look into [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance)?

Comment: What if someone did `const a1 = new A(); a2 = new A(); a2.classB = a1.classB; const b = a2.classB; b.calledFromA()` - what name would you expect to print then? In short, no you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining a `B` object in class `A`, methods and data members of class `B` can be accessed.

```js
class A {
  name = 'empty';
  objectB = null;                  /* Object B is defined as a data member. */
  
  constructor(name, city){
    this.name = name;
    this.objectB = new B(city);    /* Object B is initialized using the constructor. */
  }
}

class B {
  city = 'empty';
  
  constructor(city)
  {
    this.city = city;
  }
}

objectA = new A('john', 'london');
console.log('Name: ', objectA.name);
console.log('City: ', objectA.objectB.city);
```

Comment: Good enough for me

Comment: @LeonardoPetrucci Thanks, I hope it works for you. :)